# Unexpected output from lex program

Tags: lex

I have written a simple lex program to perform average of positive numbers ,  the program is compiling fine but i'm not able to get the expected output.I'm passing the input to the program from a file by giving filename as a commandline argument.The output of the lex program is blank showing no result , i'm a beginner in lex and any help would be appreciated . I have attached the code  below. The code is written in redhat linux kernel version 2.4.

```
 %{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 %}

%%
[0-9]+ return atoi(yytext);
%%

void main()
{
  int val, total = 0, n = 0;
  while ( (val = yylex()) > 0 ) {
  total += val;
  n++;
}
if (n > 0) printf(“ave = %d\n”, total/n);
}
```

The input file contains numbers 3,6 and 4 and the name of the file is passed as command line argument.

```
./a.out < input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program works for me. I'm a bit suspicious of `yywrap` missing, so you probably link with the `-lfl` (or something alike) option. This library contains a `yywrap` and a `main`. Even though I'm not able to reproduce what you see, I'm wary that maybe the `main` from `libfl` is used. I'm assuming you do get any newlines in the input file on the output. Different linkers have different ways of resolving multiple occurrences of the same symbol.

All in all I think you have to look for the problem in the way your program is built, because the specification seems ok. If you add `int yywrap(void) { return 1; }` after your `main`, then you can do without `libfl`, which is what I would advise any user of `lex` and `gnu-flex`.

Comment: Hello Bryan,I made a mistake in the code , the main code has to take the command line arguments hence it should be modified as main(int argc,char *argv[]) and after modifying the same i could get the o/p .I even introduced the checks for spaces and tabs and the o/p is fine .Thanks for your help .